# How to build 'ipa' with cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap, cordova-ios

I develop a hybrid app with cordova the `apk` for android was built successfully  and now i want to make `ipa` file for to run my app on apple phones. I have distribution certificate `.mobileprovison` file and `.p12` files.I successfully build the `ipa` with phonegap but i want to custom build with cordova how to do that.

What i tried so far

```
cordova build ios --device
```

but iam facing this error that `xcodebuild not present`

as below

```
PS C:\Users\A.BASIT\phonegap\tmp\userapp> cordova build ios
(node:16504) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): xcodebuild was not found. Please install version 7.0.0 or 
greater from App Store
(node:16504) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mac to build IOS apps.

Either locally or using [remote build](https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild)